# SQL Server Agent 2012 Job Schedule Report

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssms, jobs, reporting, sql-server-agent

I am looking for a report that will display graphically what jobs are scheduled on the server and when. My goal is to very quickly be able to glance at it and find a time where a new job will not interfere with other jobs.

I have been looking at the "Standard" reports but have not seen anything...I'm pretty sure I could make one...but just wanted to be sure I wasn't missing something if the wheel had already been invented and packaged with SSMS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you expand the SQL Server Agent in SSMS and double click the Job Activity Monitor you should see what you need.