# How to query Job Activity Monitor to get a list of all jobs

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-agent

I am trying to obtain a list of **ALL** jobs (SQL Agent jobs). Specifically, I am trying to obtain the ID, name, status, LastRunOutcome, Last Run, Next Run, **and** *most importantly* description, owner AND schedule (eg. *Every day at 5am*) of each job.

I know that you can obtain all of this information through Job Activity Monitor window and then by clicking on each job. But I need to query this information.

My research [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/142051/documenting-ssrs-and-ssis-jobs-that-are-the-job-activity-monitor) , [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/14524/get-a-list-of-sql-server-agent-jobs) and [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/80646/sql-server-agent-2012-job-schedule-report) included a few articles that give partial info, but not complete one.

Any help in getting a full list of active and inactive jobs and their info is much appreciated. Thank you.

I have this code so far, which I hope is accurate:

```
SELECT
     job.job_id,
     notify_level_email,
     name,
     enabled,
     description,
     step_name,
     command,
     server,
     database_name
FROM
    msdb.dbo.sysjobs job
INNER JOIN 
    msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps steps        
ON
    job.job_id = steps.job_id
```

Comment: Try this https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/148324/104102

Answer (score 2):

This gets you just about everything you mention and you can modify further to suit your needs:

```
SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar(128), SERVERPROPERTY('Servername')) AS
Server,
msdb.dbo.sysjobs.job_id,
msdb.dbo.sysjobs.name,
msdb.dbo.sysjobs.enabled AS Job_Enabled,
msdb.dbo.sysjobs.description,
msdb.dbo.sysjobs.notify_level_eventlog,
msdb.dbo.sysjobs.notify_level_email,
msdb.dbo.sysjobs.notify_level_netsend,
msdb.dbo.sysjobs.notify_level_page,
msdb.dbo.sysjobs.notify_email_operator_id,
msdb.dbo.sysjobs.date_created,
msdb.dbo.syscategories.name AS Category_Name,
msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules.next_run_date,
msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules.next_run_time,
msdb.dbo.sysjobservers.last_run_outcome,
msdb.dbo.sysjobservers.last_outcome_message,
msdb.dbo.sysjobservers.last_run_date,
msdb.dbo.sysjobservers.last_run_time,
msdb.dbo.sysjobservers.last_run_duration,
msdb.dbo.sysoperators.name AS Notify_Operator,
msdb.dbo.sysoperators.email_address,
msdb.dbo.sysjobs.date_modified,
GETDATE() AS Package_run_date,
msdb.dbo.sysschedules.name AS Schedule_Name,
msdb.dbo.sysschedules.enabled,
msdb.dbo.sysschedules.freq_type,
msdb.dbo.sysschedules.freq_interval,
msdb.dbo.sysschedules.freq_subday_interval,
msdb.dbo.sysschedules.freq_subday_type,
msdb.dbo.sysschedules.freq_relative_interval,
msdb.dbo.sysschedules.freq_recurrence_factor,
msdb.dbo.sysschedules.active_start_date,
msdb.dbo.sysschedules.active_end_date,
msdb.dbo.sysschedules.active_start_time,
msdb.dbo.sysschedules.active_end_time,
msdb.dbo.sysschedules.date_created AS
Date_Sched_Created,
msdb.dbo.sysschedules.date_modified AS
Date_Sched_Modified,
msdb.dbo.sysschedules.version_number,
msdb.dbo.sysjobs.version_number AS Job_Version
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.syscategories ON
msdb.dbo.sysjobs.category_id = msdb.dbo.syscategories.category_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysoperators ON
msdb.dbo.sysjobs.notify_page_operator_id = msdb.dbo.sysoperators.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobservers ON
msdb.dbo.sysjobs.job_id = msdb.dbo.sysjobservers.job_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules ON
msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules.job_id = msdb.dbo.sysjobs.job_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysschedules ON
msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules.schedule_id = msdb.dbo.sysschedules.schedule_id
WHERE msdb.dbo.sysjobs.enabled = 1
--AND msdb.dbo.sysjobservers.last_run_outcome = 0
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I apologize if I am missing something here but I am not able to get the most important information here: the occurrence schedule, for example: "occurs weekly at 5am". I looked into the freq_% fields there but they seem to be flags and not schedules.